# Undefined method `has_attached_file` with Paperclip and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm having some trouble getting Paperclip working on my VPS. It works fine locally and on my first VPS, but when I try to `rake db:migrate` on the second VPS, I get the following output:

```
root@Test:/home/rails# rake db:migrate
==  CreateGroups: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:groups)
   -> 0.0019s
-- add_column(:discussions, :group_id, :integer)
   -> 0.0007s
-- add_column(:memberships, :memberships_id, :integer)
   -> 0.0006s
-- has_attached_file(:photo, {:styles=>{:original=>"400x200>", :tile=>"200x200#"}, :url=>"/assets/images/groups/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", :path=>":rails_root/public/assets/images/groups/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", :default_url=>"/assets/:style/missing-group-image.jpg"})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<CreateGroups:0x0000000342cbf8>/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:465:in `block in method_missing'
...
```

What I've done so far to set up this second VPS is:

- set up Unicorn + Nginx (they seem to be working fine)
- `apt-get install git`
- `apt-get install imagemagick`
- `bundle install` (and Paperclip is in my Gemfile)
- restarted my shell
- rebooted the VPS

After all of this, I'm still getting the above error whenever I try to migrate. Any ideas of what to do next?

Comment: Which version o paperclip?

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't quite follow Paperclip installation guide. You should have following migration (copied from Paperclip readme so may slightly differ for you)

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :users, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

and you apparently put there something that should be in you MODEL.

Comment: My migrations on this VPS are exactly the same as my migrations locally and on my development VPS, and Paperclip works there without a problem; I don't think that a missing migration is the issue. 

I also do have a AddAttachmentPhotoToProjects migration as well as a AddAttachmentFileToProjectFiles migration included (I made them through the Paperclip generator that the readme mentions).

Comment: You have this `-- has_attached_file(:photo, {:styles=>{:original=>"400x200>", :tile=>"200x200#"}, :url=>"/assets/images/groups/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", :path=>":rails_root/public/assets/images/groups/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", :default_url=>"/assets/:style/missing-group-image.jpg"})
` in migration so please don't tell me your migrations are ok.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my issue had more to do with incomplete code than my environment. Turns out that a teammate of mine had pushed some incomplete code to our GitHub repository, and I hadn't noticed it.

By doing `git logs`, choosing the right commit, and then `git checkout (...)`, I was able to migrate and seed my database and run my application as expected.

I feel very silly for spending over an hour trying to figure that out, but hopefully it helps someone else. :)